# How do I configure docker to allow a connection to a container from other computers?

Tags: docker

I am trying to run a small test server with MS SQL Server running on a Mac in a Linux docker container.  Maybe I have the terminology wrong so please correct me if necessary:

host - the macOS desktop with docker installed (ip 10.0.1.73)

container - the Linux instance running in the docker container with SQL Server running in it

remote desktop - another computer on the local area network trying to connect to SQL Server

I followed the MS installation instructions and everything seems to be running fine, except I can't connect to SQL Server from the Remote Desktop

I can connect to the docker host(10.0.1.73) and can ping the IP address

I can connect to SQL Server from the docker host and see the databases etc.

I used the following command to create the docker container

```
sudo docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=<XXXXXX>"  -p 1433:1433 --name sqlserver1   -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
```

Thinking that the `-p 1433:1433` would map the linux port to the macOS host port and allow the remote computer to access the docker container when connecting to that port on the macOS host from the local area network

This is not working and I assume this may be to do with the network routing on the macOS host

Most solutions I have seen seem to indicate that one should use the VirtualBox UI to modify the network settings - but I don't have that installed

The others seem to have pages and pages of command line instructions that are required

Is there an easy solution somewhere I have missed?

EDIT:

Some more research and I found this explanation about how by default the Docker networking is set up for single host networking.  Good explanation for anyone else struggling with the Docker concepts.

It is also worth reading up about the differences between docker containers and virtual machines...

https://youtu.be/Js_140tDlVI

Still trying to find some explanation on multi host networking.

Comment: Docker for Mac, or Docker Toolbox?  (Do you have the "whale" icon on your menu bar?  Do you ever run a `docker-machine` command?)

Comment: I have the Whale icon - which is Docker for Mac I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using NAT:

1. Assign the target address to your host interface:

   ```
   sudo ifconfig en1 alias 10.0.1.74/21 up
   ```
2. Create the docker container and map the port to the second IP address assigned to the host interface

   ```
   sudo docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=<XXXXXXXXX>" -p 10.0.1.74:1433:1433 --name sqlserver1 -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
   ```

Answer (score 1):

try disabeling the firewall on the host you want to connect to.

port 1433 will be forwarded to the docker container, but your host (MAC) should have port 1433 open to be able to connect to your host.

Comment: Firewall is off

Comment: From what I can tell I need to set up some sort of bridge network.

Comment: your docker container will by default not access your LAN. it will be only accesable in from your host with a 172... IP (out the top of my head). But if you connect to your host on port 1433, this should be forwarded to the container anyway I think